# Retrofit 2 is not receiving response inside AsyncTask every 1, 3, 5... time

Tags: android, asynchronous, retrofit

I am using Retrofit to receive response, but every 1st, 3rd, 5th... time there is no response coming after Button click (I checked by Postman or Webbrowser in different networks - there is always response). In debug mode every second time is not even entering to `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` methods:

This is my **MainActivity.class**

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...//some not important code

        Button syncButton = findViewById(R.id.syncBtn);
        syncButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AsyncTaskRunner asyncTaskRunner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                asyncTaskRunner.execute();

            }
        });
    }
```

This is my **AsyncTaskRunner.class**:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<GetCheapestResponseType>> {

        @Override
        protected List<GetCheapestResponseType> doInBackground(String... strings) {

            ...//some not important code

            MutableLiveData<List<GetCheapestResponseType>> getCheapestResponseTypeMutableListData = new MutableLiveData<>();

            List<GetCheapestResponseType> getCheapestResponseTypeList = new LinkedList<>();

            ...//some not important code


            MutableLiveData<GetCheapestResponseType> getCheapestResponseTypeMutableLiveData = getCheapestOneWay(...);
                        getCheapestResponseTypeList.add(getCheapestResponseTypeMutableLiveData.getValue());

           ...//some not important code

            return getCheapestResponseTypeList.add(getCheapestResponseTypeMutableLiveData.getValue());
        }
 }
```

This is my `getCheapestOneWay(...);` method with Retrofit:

```
public MutableLiveData<GetCheapestResponseType> getCheapestOneWay(...) {

        ...//some not important code

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(urlGetCheapest)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        Controller controller = retrofit.create(Controller.class);

        Call<GetCheapestResponseType> callAsync = controller.getCheapest(...);

        callAsync.enqueue(new Callback<GetCheapestResponseType>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<GetCheapestResponseType> call, Response<GetCheapestResponseType> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    GetCheapestResponseType apiResponse = response.body();

                    mutableLiveData.postValue(apiResponse);
                } else {
                    ...//some not important code
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<GetCheapestResponseType> call, Throwable throwable) {
                ...//some not important code
            }
        });
        return mutableLiveData;
    }
```